# Find input method ID from inside keyboard service

Tags: android, ime

How can you get the ID of a keyboard service you have written? I've tried using the `InputMethodInfo` class' method `getId()`, but it returns an ID that is different than the one returned from the `Settings.Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver, Settings.ACTION_INPUT_METHOD_SETTINGS)` .

Answer (score 0):

`ACTION_INPUT_METHOD_SETTINGS` is for launching Settings app, you should not be using it to get input method ID. [Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_INPUT_METHOD_SETTINGS):

> **public static final String ACTION_INPUT_METHOD_SETTINGS**
>
> **Activity Action: Show settings to configure input methods, in particular allowing the user to enable input methods.**

[`getId()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodInfo.html#getId%28%29) is the correct API.